# Programmatically restart a Live Wallpaper?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

Is there a way for a Live Wallpaper to restart itself?

Comment: Why would you want/need to do this?

Comment: The reason is because I'm writing a wallpaper that uses FFmpeg via NDK. I think the NDK version of FFmpeg may be buggy---I can't seem to free the video frame on orientation changes. It seems easier to just restart the wallpaper (and therefore, reset the memory) than hunt down the library memory leak... Yeah, it's a hack

Comment: Yup just confirmed it, there seems to be something wrong with av_freep(). Any how, restarting the wallpaper seems like a quick hack that'll get the job done

Comment: What do you mean by "the NDK version of FFmpeg"?  I thought there were many ports, or you could compile your own.  Either way, you might be able to get around this by using a different implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a reference to a google post by one of the android devs that I can't find now, while you can stop a live wallpaper, you can't start it yourself---it's a security issue. So the answer is that this can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

Being a Service, have you tried using [stopService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf%28%29)?  Not sure how to start it up again, though.

Comment: no that doesn't work (although that's probably the approach). Still how to restart?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try a different ffmpeg implementation to avoid the bug?  [This guy](http://ikaruga2.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/video-live-wallpaper-part-1/) used [bambuser's](http://bambuser.com/opensource) version.

Comment: That's actually me :-) Rotating the video doesn't work. Well, at least on the client's phone. Either it's OpenGL, FFmpeg, the client's phone, or a combination of all three. Either way, the best solution (although a hack) is starting to look like restarting the wallpaper.

Comment: Haha, that's great.  I was just shooting in the dark, no idea where to go from there.  Good luck!